# How to select the cell on mouse click and shift in JGrid similar to (JTable)?

Tags: java, jtable, listener, keylistener, listselectionlistener

I have the `ListSelectionListener` which tells me when the cell is selected with the mouse.

```
JGrid grid = new JGrid();
grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
grid.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

   @Override
   public void valueChanged(final ListSelectionEvent e) {
       e.getFirstIndex();
       e.getLastIndex()
   }
}
```

I want  to select the sell only when the button shift is hold. How can i do it?

I need it for the multiple selection. When the user holds shift and clicks the cells it gives me `getFirstIndex()` and  `getLastIndex()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a KeyListener similar to this to your JGrid, assuming JGrids takes keyListeners

```
boolean shiftIsDown = false;

yourJGrid.addKeyListener(new KeyListener()
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getKeyCode == e.VK_SHIFT) shiftIsDown = true; 
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
            {
                 if (e.getKeyCode == e.VK_SHIFT && 
                     shiftIsDown == true) shiftIsDown = false;
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
            {
                // nothing
            }

        });
```

Now when you get a valueChanged() event, just check to see if your boolean "shiftIsDown" value is true, and if so you can do your selection.